# ModuleNotFoundError when running a Python script from the command prompt/Run window (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows

I've been following the Automate the Boring Stuff with Python book and I'm stuck on chapter 6's chapter project - multi-clipboard automatic messages. Here is the code:

```
#! python3
# mclip.py - A multi-clipboard program.

import sys, pyperclip

TEXT = {"agree": """Yes I agree, that sounds fine to me.""",
        "busy": """Sorry, can we do this next week or later this week?""",
        "upsell": """Would you consider making this a monthly donation?"""}

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Usage: python mclip.py [keyphrase] - copy phrase text")
    sys.exit()

keyphrase = sys.argv[1]

if keyphrase in TEXT:
    pyperclip.copy(TEXT[keyphrase])
    print("Text for " + keyphrase + " copied to clipboard.")
else:
    print("There is no text for " + keyphrase + ".")
```

Here is the notepad batch file I've created, it is located at C:\Windows\mclip.bat :

```
@py.exe C:\Users\ayram\PycharmProjects\ATBS\mclip.py %*
@pause
```

When I use "mclip.py agree" in the Run window or in the command prompt, it says that there is no command with this name. But when I type "mclip agree" instead, it says there is no module named pyperclip and I get the ModuleNotFoundError. When I use pyperclip.copy() and pyperclip.paste() in my IDE (python 3.10 - PyCharm), it works just fine though, so it seems that the IDE recognizes the module but not Windows? Any idea as to what the problem could be? Complete beginner here.

Thank you

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you have very common problem which you can see in many questions. You may have two Pythons installed and you installed module in one Python but you run code with second Python - but pythons don't share modules. IDE could install own version of Python. Maybe in IDE use `print( sys.executable )` to see `\full\path\to\python.exe` and later use `\full\path\to\python.exe` instead of `py.exe`

Comment: @furas I think you may be right. I did have to go from Python 3.8 to 3.10 within the IDE so the pyperclip module could work. However, I tried your method of replacing `@py.exe` by `@C:\Users\ayram\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.10.exe` in the batch file but I still have the same ModuleNotFoundError. Did I follow your instructions right? Thank you

Comment: maybe you have another python in different folder - you should check in IDE `print(sys.executable)` to get correct path. Maybe IDE installed own Python and it uses different path. You can also check somewher in `settings` what Python is used in IDE and you can  even change path to use your `C:\Users\ayram\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.10.exe`. OR use `C:\Users\ayram\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.10.exe -m pip install ... ` to install modules in this Python too.

Comment: @furas The `C:\Users\ayram\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.10.exe` is the one used in my IDE which I found with `print(sys.executable)`. Is there a way for Windows to use this python and forget py.exe which is the 3.8 version?

Comment: you can always remove `py.exe` and put `python3.10.exe` in its place with name `py.exe`